# Why is train loss and validate loss both in a straight line?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using Conv-LSTM for training, and the input features have been proven to be effective in some papers, and I can use CNN+FC networks to extract features and classify them. I change the task to regression here, and I can also achieve model convergence with Conv+FC. Later, I tried to use Conv-LSTM for processing to consider the timing characteristics of the corresponding data. Specifically: return the output of the current moment based on multiple historical inputs and the input of the current moment. The Conv-LSTM code I used: https://github.com/ndrplz/ConvLSTM_pytorch. My Loss is L1-Loss and optimizer is Adam.

A loss curve is below:

[image]

Example loss value:

```
Epoch:1/500 AVG Training Loss:16.40108 AVG Valid Loss:22.40100

Best validation loss: 22.400997797648113

Saving best model for epoch 1

Epoch:2/500 AVG Training Loss:16.42522 AVG Valid Loss:22.40100
Epoch:3/500 AVG Training Loss:16.40599 AVG Valid Loss:22.40100
Epoch:4/500 AVG Training Loss:16.40175 AVG Valid Loss:22.40100
Epoch:5/500 AVG Training Loss:16.42198 AVG Valid Loss:22.40101
Epoch:6/500 AVG Training Loss:16.41907 AVG Valid Loss:22.40101
Epoch:7/500 AVG Training Loss:16.42531 AVG Valid Loss:22.40101
```

My attempt:

1. Adjust the data set to only a few samples, verify that it can be overfitted, and the network code should be fine.[image: small dataset]
2. Adjusting the learning rate, I tried 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5 and 1e-6, but the loss curve is still flat as before, and even the value of the loss curve has not changed much.
3. Replace the optimizer with SGD, and the training result is also the above problem.

Because my data is wireless data (I-Q), neither CV nor NLP input type, here are some questions to ask about deep learning training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I finally found that my initial learning rate was too small. According to my previous single-point data training, the learning rate of 1e-3 is large enough, so here is preconceived, and it is adjusted from 1e-3 to a small tune, but in fact, the learning rate of 1e-3 is too small, resulting in the network not learning at all. Later, the learning rate was adjusted to 1e-2, and both the train loss and validate loss of the network achieved rapid decline (And the optimizer is Adam). When adjusting the learning rate later, you can start from 1 to the minor, do not preconceive.

[image: final figure]